# How to Capture Errors When Using Restsharp & System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, json, error-handling, restsharp

I am using RestSharp in my project but when I try to connect to an endpoint. I am getting an error but it is not being captured. The deserialization goes ahead on the object and just returns null instead of throwing an error.

If I was not using deserialization I probably could look at the http status code but that is all hidden.

For instance I have code like ths

```
var request = new RestRequest("address/update").AddJsonBody(updatedAddress);
var response = await client.PostAsync<AddressUpdateResponse>(request);
```

all I will see in "response" is null. I can't get any other information.

I read this in their error handling section.

> WARNING
>
> Please be aware that deserialization failures will only work if the serializer throws an exception when deserializing the response. Many serializers don't throw by default, and just return a null result. RestSharp is unable to figure out why null is returned, so it won't fail in this case. Check the serializer documentation to find out if it can be configured to throw on deserialization error.

I am using System.Text.Json but not sure how to do this.

Comment: "I am using RestSharp", dont use RestSharp.  Why people are looking for the problems? What do you think you gain using RestSharp? Or try to use HttpClietn just for testing.

Comment: When you have two line of code  one brings json, another deserializing, you can check what is the problem - deserializing or httpresponse. But people try to put everything in one line and after this asking what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `PostAsync<T>`, RestSharp will try deserialising the response using the model type you provided as `T`. However, the error response might not be deserialisable as `T`, so you get `null` back.

You can use `ExecutePostAsync<T>`, which will return an instance of `RestResponse<T>`. It will contain both the `Data` property of `T`, and the `Content` property of `string`. When you get a proper result, the `Data` property will contain the deserialised result. If the call fails and the server returns an error, you can check the `Content` property for error details. If the error content is JSON, you can deserialise it using any JSON deserialiser, including `System.Text.Json`.

Comment: Cool, I see that it also has Exception/Exception Message can I check those or is checking the Content the best thing to look for the error? I am just not sure what Content will actually contain back.

Comment: The Exception property is populated only if the request fails upstream (in HttpClient). It will be basically the same BadRequest exception that is thrown by PostAsync. To find out what the Content is just try it out and log it when it’s an error.